# PHP OAuth with the LinkedIn API

Tags: php, oauth, pecl

I'm running into problems making requests to the LinkedIn share API using PHP's PECL OAuth module. I've Googled for all I'm worth, but I can't find any examples.

My PHP Code:

```
$linkedin_oauth = new OAuth($linkedin_consumer_key,$linkedin_consumer_secret,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM);
  $linkedin_oauth->setToken($linkedin_data->linkedin_token, $linkedin_data->linkedin_consumer_secret);
  $linkedin_oauth->setAuthType(OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_FORM);

  $body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
  $body .= "<share>";
  $body .= "<comment>83% of employers will use social media to hire: 78% LinkedIn, 55% Facebook, 45% Twitter [SF Biz Times] http://bit.ly/cCpeOD</comment>";
  $body .= "<content>";
  $body .= "<title>Survey: Social networks top hiring tool - San Francisco Business Times</title>";
  $body .= "<submitted-url>http://sanfrancisco.bizjournals.com/sanfrancisco/stories/2010/06/28/daily34.html</submitted-url>";
  $body .= "<submitted-image-url>http://images.bizjournals.com/travel/cityscapes/thumbs/sm_sanfrancisco.jpg</submitted-image-url>";
  $body .= "</content>";
  $body .= "<visibility>";
  $body .= "<code>anyone</code>";
  $body .= "</visibility>";
  $body .= "</share>";

$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml');
  $linkedin_oauth->fetch("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares", $body, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
  $linkedin_share_response = $linkedin_oauth->getLastResponse();
```

But this results in an exception:

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```

My headers look like:

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<KEY_REMOVED>",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_nonce="12581672284fa32618a44a31.27944550",oauth_timestamp="1336092184",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_token="<TOKEN_REMOVED>",oauth_signature="Qqt5zQKITSvk7OyrdWdFLaR%2F9ns%3D
```

Does anyone have any idea whats going on here? Regardless of what I do, the response is always a 401.

When I replace with call with a GET call, it works fine.

Comment: Your content type is set to text/xml, so you are sending an xml document to the server.  It looks like it is expected an HTTP header.  How does your get call look, the difference between the two could be the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Check return URL in your registered OAuth application. It must be your script’s URL.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a lot of info on the web about this stuff but this seems to work for me.  If your using OAuth2.0 access tokens this should work.  Plug and chug your variables in and let me know if you have any problems.

```
$params = array(
    'oauth2_access_token'   => $oauth2_access_token
);

$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?' . http_build_query($params);

$xml_content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><share><content><title>' . $title . '</title><submitted-url>' . $link . '</submitted-url><submitted-image-url>' . $image . '</submitted-image-url></content><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>';


$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'content'   => $xml_content,
        'header'    => "Content-type: application/xml"
    )
));

$stream = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);

if ($stream) {
    $metaData = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
    $response = stream_get_contents($stream);
    fclose($stream);
}
```